# Pass nested document query field

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to make a generic method which can query in the same way for more than one nested query field:

```
MyClass.prototype.myFind = function(myCollection, queryField, myValue, callback){
    myCollection.find({queryField : myValue}, callback)
}
```

(Obviously there is no point to this query, mine is more complicated, but not in a way related to the question)

The problem is that `queryField`, passing in `"myField.myNestedField"` to the method doesn't seem to work, but when I do the same query with `"myField.myNestedField"` it does work. Is there a way to pass in a nested query field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a JavaScript one and that the document will always be sent as "queryfield" and not the variable that you are passing in no matter what the notation of it.

You basically need to use the "bracket" `[]` notation to correctly interpolate a variable as the field to use:

```js
MyClass.prototype.myFind = function(myCollection, queryField, myValue, callback){
    var query = {};
    query[queryField] = myValue;
    myCollection.find(query, callback)
}
```

And now it always works as expected.